# pass relative url in signalR hub connection

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, signalr, signalr-hub

I am trying to implement signalR in angularJS, 
I want to pass relative url to hub connection, but it's making current url (on which my angular application is hosted)

My API base url : `http://localhost:81/NrsService/api/TestSignal`

My angular application running at

```
http://localhost:81
```

Here is my signalR setup :

```
$.connection.hub.url = "/NrsService/api/TestSignal";
//Getting the connection object
connection = $.hubConnection();
```

Like it is sending request at  `http://localhost:81/signalr/negotiate?` but I want it to be  `http://localhost:81/NrsService/api/TestSignal/negotiate?`

Comment: Did you find a solution yet? I have the same problem..

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit the generated JavaScript code where the client proxy is defined. As of SignalR 2.4.0 there is a createHubProxies function defined where you should find this line of code:

```
signalR.hub = $.hubConnection("/signalr", { useDefaultPath: false });
```

Change it to the following to prevent the "/signalr" ending in your requests:

```
signalR.hub = $.hubConnection("", { useDefaultPath: false });
```

After that, you can simply change the url which should be called the way you provided in your question, e.g.:

```
$.connection.hub.url = "/NrsService/api/TestSignal";
```

If you also want to change this Url dynamically, you can use the document.location properties. In my case, I did something like this:

```
var subPath = document.location.pathname.substr(0, document.location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/"));
$.connection.hub.url = subPath;      // subpath equals to "/NrsService/api"
```

Hope this helps.